# ajax y PHP funciona bien local pero no en host

Tags: php, html, ajax

Actualizacion 22/01/2020*

esto me trae de regreso el json al consultar midominio.com/ajax.php?valor=5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

forzando el valor dentro del codigo de ajax.php si me extrae los todos los campos solicitados.

pero parece que el error esta en el json, segun un console log el formulario de slect la funcion ajax si recibe el valor que se le envia desde el select.

aqui las imagenes tambien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Forzando el valor]

Actualizacion*

si hago una consulta directa en el host forzando un valor en pantalla si me devuelve el dato de la consulta.

```
    <?php
 $query = "SELECT materia, curso, grupo, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, instructora, capacidad, precio FROM cursos20201 WHERE cod_materia='5'";
    $r = mysqli_query( $con, $query ) or die( mysqli_error() );
    $resultados = mysqli_fetch_array( $r );

    echo($resultados['materia']);
?>
```

Esto indica que la funcion de ajax no esta enviando el valor de la variable valor que necesito
**que esta mal con el codigo de script de mifuncion(valor)?**
[image: Esto indica que la funcion de ajax no esta enviando el valor de la variable valor que necesito]

para quienes han estado ayudando, ayer averigue este error que me sale:

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

no encuentro en que parte del JSON se encuentra este error.

Tengo un select que trae datos desde una base de datos el cura funciona bien tanto en mi host como en el servidor local esto lo complemento con una función de Js, AJAX y php, esto con el selector relleno varios inputs
Aquí la función de Js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mifuncion(valor){



    $.ajax({
        // la URL para la petición

        url : "ajax.php",

        // la información a enviar en este caso el valor de lo que seleccionaste en el select
        data : { valor:valor },

        // especifica si será una petición POST o GET
        type : "POST",

        // el tipo de información que se espera de respuesta
        dataType : "json",

        // código a ejecutar si la petición es satisfactoria;
        success : function(json) {
            //aqui recibimos el "echo" del php(ajax.php)
            //y ahora solo colocas el valor en los campos

            document.getElementById("txtMater").value=json.materia;
    document.getElementById("cursos").value=json.curso
            document.getElementById("costo").value=json.precio;
            document.getElementById("txtIntru").value=json.instructora;
            document.getElementById("txtGrup").value=json.grupo;
            document.getElementById("txtCaps").value=json.capacidad;
            document.getElementById("txtLunes").value=json.lunes;
            document.getElementById("txtmartes").value=json.martes;
            document.getElementById("txtmiercoles").value=json.miercoles;
            document.getElementById("txtjueves").value=json.jueves;
            document.getElementById("txtviernes").value=json.viernes;
            document.getElementById("txtsabado").value=json.sabado;



        },

        // código a ejecutar si la petición falla;
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Error al ejecutar => " + textStatus + " – " + errorThrown);


        }

});


}
        </script>
```

luego hago la petición de los datos a a la base de datos

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","facultad_artes","Eu24Niche89+*","facultad_cursos") or die (mysqli_error());

$valor=$_POST['valor'];

$jsondata = array();

$query="SELECT materia, curso, grupo, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, instructora, capacidad, precio FROM cursos20201 WHERE cod_materia=$valor";
$r=mysqli_query($con, $query);
$resultados= mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$materia = $resultados[ 'materia' ];
$curso = $resultados[ 'curso' ];
$grupo = $resultados[ 'grupo' ];
$lunes = $resultados[ 'lunes' ];
$martes = $resultados[ 'martes' ];
$miercoles = $resultados[ 'miercoles' ];
$jueves = $resultados[ 'jueves' ];
$viernes = $resultados[ 'viernes' ];
$sabado = $resultados[ 'sabado' ];
$instructora = $resultados[ 'instructora' ];
$capacidad = $resultados[ 'capacidad' ];
$precio = $resultados[ 'precio' ];



    //agregamos nuestros datos al array para retornarlos
$jsondata[ 'materia' ] = $materia;
$jsondata[ 'curso' ] = $curso;
$jsondata[ 'precio' ] = $precio;
$jsondata[ 'instructora' ] = $instructora;
$jsondata[ 'grupo' ] = $grupo;
$jsondata[ 'capacidad' ] = $capacidad;
$jsondata[ 'lunes' ] = $lunes;
$jsondata[ 'martes' ] = $martes;
$jsondata[ 'miercoles' ] = $miercoles;
$jsondata[ 'jueves' ] = $jueves;
$jsondata[ 'viernes' ] = $viernes;
$jsondata[ 'sabado' ] = $sabado;



     echo json_encode($jsondata); 
     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Despues de todo esto como comento de forma local todo funciona bien me llena los campos input del formulario que quiero llenar y funciona correctamente, pero en la puesta a prueba en un host real no funciona el coodigo y me tira el error 
   **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

de aqui es donde recojo el dato, desde un select.

```
<select class="form-control" name="mate" id="mate" onChange="mifuncion(this.value)"  >
<option value="" selected disabled>Selecciona una opcion</option>
    <?php

$re = mysqli_query( $cn, "SELECT cod_materia, materia FROM cursos20201" );

while ( $f = mysqli_fetch_array( $re ) ) {

$c = $f['cod_materia'];

    $t = $f['materia'];

echo '<option value=' . $c. '>' . $t . '</option>';

        }
                                ?>
    </select>
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

actualizacion!

si forzo un valor dentro de ajax.php me devuelve esto

[image: Esto me muestra el navegador Firefox Developer Edition]

y esto me sale en el eror_log de mi host

[image: las lineas que marca con error son todas donde se almacena en resultado de la consulta]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103594/discussion-on-question-by-mike-damian-ajax-y-php-funciona-bien-local-pero-no-en).

Comment: lo intente, pero como soy nuevo, no me dejaba, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

prueba ingresando comillas en el arreglo cuando llamas al nombre del campo de la base de datos.
Ej:
$f["cod_materia"]
$f["materia"]

También puedes probar con números
$f[0];
$f[1];

Nos faltaría más información del error que esta mostrando, también podrías colocar información de la base de datos para ver si tus campos no comienzan con mayúscula.
Ej: Cod_materia, puede que algunas versiones sean case sensitive.

Comment: Hola Cristobal, muchas gracias por tu apoyo, fijate que los campos estan correctos en la base de datos, ahora si observas en el apartado ajax.php, hago uso de $valor, y revisando el error_log me aparece esto: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: valor, esto en la parte comentada donde enviamos el dato en la variable valor, despues de eso, pues la verdad es que la base de datos solo tiene un diferencia, en mi localhost se maneja como utf8mb4_unicode_ci y en el host esta como latin1_swedish_ci, sera que ahi radica el problema?